# Junction SQL Query back to First Table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, junction-table

I have some MS Access 2010 `link tables` that links back to the first table, like so:

```
    Item                LinkTable

[ ID       ]           [ ID        ]
[ ItemName ]-1-------*-[ FromItem  ]
[          ]-1-------*-[ ToItem    ]
```

*Fig.1: **`FromItem`** and **`ToItem`** references **'Item.ID'***

I would like to make a query that links together all three tables and display for example the follwoing fields

(from)**Item.ItemName** | **LinkTable.ID** | (to)**Item.ItemName**

I have tried the following SQL, but it complains about the second occurence of Item, with a message "Can't repeat table name "Item" in the FROM clause" in the expression "Item LEFT JOIN LinkTable" below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Item LEFT JOIN 
(
Item LEFT JOIN LinkTable ON (LinkTable.ToItem =Item.ID)
)
ON (LinkTable.FromItem = Item.ID);
```

**Q1:** Why can't I link back to the "starting table" like this without causing an error message?

**Q2:** How should I define the Select fields in order to show both the from-ItemName and the to-ItemName without confusing them? (In the example I wrote "Select *" to simplify)

// Rolf

**Edit:______________________________________________________**

Based on the reply by @Andomar (below) I ended up with the following working code. I used `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` in order to get only matching `Items` :

```
   SELECT fro.ItemName
   ,      lt.ID
   ,      to.ItemName
   FROM Item fro 
   INNER JOIN (LinkTable lt 
   INNER JOIN Item to ON lt.toItem = to.ID)
   ON fro.ID = lt.fromItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias a table name.  For example, this aliases the table `Item` to the alias `i1`:

```
FROM   Item i1
```

You can now use the same table again and use a different alias to identify it.  Combining this with the parenthesis Access requires for multiple joins, you get:

```
SELECT  i1.ItemName
,       i2.ItemName
FROM (Item i1
LEFT JOIN LinkTable lt ON lt.FromItem = i1.ID)
LEFT JOIN item i2 ON i2.ID = lt.ToItem
```